# Перевод в другую систему счисления на PHP

Tags: php, системы-счисления

Как из десятичной системы перевести число в восьмеричную? Какая есть для этого функция?

Answer (score 3):

**в php:**

```
base_convert($num, 10, 8);
```

или

```
decoct ($num);
```

**Алгоритм проверки следующий:**

1. Делим десятичное число А на 8. Частное Q запоминаем для следующего
   шага, а остаток a записываем как младший бит восьмеричного числа.
2. Если частное q не равно 0, принимаем его за новое делимое и
   повторяем процедуру, описанную в шаге 1. Каждый новый остаток
   записывается в разряды восьмеричного числа в направлении от младшего
   бита к старшему.
3. Алгоритм продолжается до тех пор, пока в результате
   выполнения шагов 1 и 2 не получится частное Q = 0 и остаток a меньше
   8.